# Need to dump my domain host and just point to IP addresses

Tags: dns

I bought my domain with a hosting company but I no longer need the hosting space. I am just redirecting my domain to my github pages. I did that with the admin panel my host provided.
I would like to quit paying the hosting company but continue having the domain point to github. How is this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to transfer your domain to a domain host like [Namecheap](https://www.namecheap.com/) or [Godaddy](https://www.godaddy.com/). They will charge you just about $11 (based on the domain extension) to keep just your domain per year.